# Multiple sentence and document padding for text classification

Tags: keras, lstm, text-classification, recurrent-neural-network, document-classification

Given a document is made up of multiple sentences, each sentence constitutes of tokens and each token has a pre-trained vector of say 50 dimensions, I would think the tensor would be (ndocs, nsents, nwords, ndims) to classify sentences with the sequential context of a document.

In typical sentence classification, sentences are padded with 0's to get sentences of equal length and allow subsequent classification. One normally proceeds by creating a 2D embedding layer with nsamples x ntokens as input. Given that similarly, documents will not have equal number of sentences, would this require appending rows of 0's to a document?

Given the task here is sentence classification in the context of the document, this can be represented as a many-to-many problem as in the figure below, where the red units are sentences (not words). Each sentence is (nwords, ndims).

[image: Reference: Karpathy]
Source: [Karpathy](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/)

Assuming (ndocs, nsents, nwords, ndims) is the right dimensionality, how would you proceed with the embeddings layer and subsequent lstm layers?

**Questions:**

- Should documents be padded with zero rows to make all documents have equal number of sentences?
- How are the embeddings initialized in the case of (ndocs, nsents, nwords, ndims)? Is the Embedding() able to handle a list of nested token indices or should each sentence be represented by an Embedding() layer therefore ending up with:

  doc1 = [sent1_embed_layer, sent2_embed_layer, sent3_embed_layer], doc2 = [sent1_embed_layer, sent2_embed_layer, sent3_embed_layer]

and in turn:

```
embeds = [[doc1_sent1_embed_layer, doc1_sent2_embed_layer, doc1_sent3_embed_layer], [doc2_sent1_embed_layer, doc2_sent2_embed_layer, doc2_sent3_embed_layer]]
```

Adding some code below to how the data would be prepared to obtain the above data structure (assuming the tokens within each sentence were already mapped to their indices).

```
max_sent_length = 100
max_sents = 70

# pad sentences to max length and pad documents to max number of sentences
padded_docs = []
for doc in docs:
    padded_sents = []   
    for sent in doc:
        padded_sents.append(pad_sequences(sent, max_length=max_sent_length))
    padded_doc = padded_sents
    while len(padded_doc) < max_sents:
        padded_doc.append([0]*max_sent_length)

    padded_docs.append(padded_doc)

# now we have a list of docs, each consisting of an equal number of sentences, each consisting of an equal number of token indices
```